# linear regression backwards elimination

Tags: multiple-regression, t-test, residuals

Suppose we have to find the best predictive linear model for the price of residential houses in a certain area from a set of predictors such as sqft, number of baths, etc.

Also, suppose that we approach the task using a backwards selection starting from the full model containing all the predictors and removing the least significant predictor at each time using the t-test (if using R from the summary() output).

My question is: do we need to check the residual plots at each step to ensure that the residuals are normally distributed to make sure that the t-tests are valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the validity of OLS regression does not strictly require that residuals are normal, rather IID. If normal, however, OLS will be asymptotically efficient, reaching the lowest possible variance (Cramer-Rao Bound) in your estimator.

In (linear) OLS, Under strict exogeneity of residual errors, the parameter distribution looks like

$$
\hat{\beta} \sim N(\beta,(X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2)
$$

where $\sigma^2$ is the (finite) variance of your error term $\epsilon$ and $\beta$ refers to the standard point estimator result in OLS.
**This result does not require normality!!**

Normality just improves efficiency bounds in the class of BLUE estimators.

So your t-statistics should be still valid. **However, ensure that you have no endogeneity in your model, i.e., ensure that $E[\epsilon|X]=0$** holds. This is the critical part.

Comment: I understand that the OLS estimate of the coefficients doesn't require the normality of the residuals so the estimate would still be unbiased even if the residuals were not normal. However, I also thought that an assumption of the t-test in this context was that the residuals should be approximately normal. If they are not then I thought the t-test would not be valid. Hence my question whether we need to check this assumption at each step before making inferences using the t-value.

Comment: The answer is no, you do not need normality in the residuals. Most importantly, ensure that error terms and your regressors are conditionally independent.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Could you expand/point me in the right direction on why the parameter distribution, in this case, is normal?

Comment: Try to calculate the variance covariance from the point estimator $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$.

Comment: If the OP is using backwards elimination, the t-statistics will not be valid.